# Is there a shorter way to update a column with range values on Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

The update script will be like

```
UPDATE TABLE_A
SET COLUMN_A = (range values (1,10)
WHERE  COLUMN_B = 'Descriptions'
```

So that when I  run the query below

```
SELECT COLUMN_B, min(COLUMN_A ), max(COLUMN_A )
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE COLUMN_B = 'Descriptions'
group by COLUMN_B ;
```

COLUMN_A has minimum value of 1 and maximum value of 10.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. What you are trying to achieve? ultimately You are updating the value of COLUMN_A to 10 (Value in the last update statement). Also, there is no `WHERE` clause. It means each record of the table will be updated to 10

Comment: You are updating the same column with new values. Are you trying to update the row number instead of setting the whole column with the same values.

Comment: Sorry, there will be a WHERE condition like WHERE COLUMN_B = 'Descptions'

Comment: It is hard to understand what it is you are trying to achieve. Please take a step back and try to explain it as clearly as possible. It is a great help if you post create scripts with a sample dataset and provide the expected output.

Comment: Okay thanks, i updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE TABLE_A 
   SET COLUMN_A = CEIL(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE * 10) 
 WHERE COLUMN_B = 'Descriptions';
```

There is no "ranges" function in oracle, but you can emulate that using dbms_random which generates a value between 0 an 1. Multiply it by 10 so you get a value between 0 and 10 (10 will not be included). Round up (using `CEIL` function) so you get values 1 thru 10. 
Note that you will get random values between 1 and 10 in this example, there is no guarantee you have values 1 and 10 included and there will likely be duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have some sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_a ( Column_A, Column_B ) AS
SELECT   0, 'Descriptions' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, 'Descriptions' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   3, 'Range1'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   5, 'Range2'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   6, 'Range2'       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT   7, 'Range2'       FROM DUAL;
```

And you want to update `Descriptions` to have a range from 1-10 and also want to update `Range1` to have a range from 42-50 (but there is only a single row in the sample data) and `Range2` to have a range from 0-9 (but there are more than two rows in the sample data). Then you can use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_a dst
USING (
  WITH ranges ( Column_A, Column_B, rn ) AS (
    SELECT  1, 'Descriptions', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 10, 'Descriptions', 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 42, 'Range1',       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 50, 'Range1',       0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  0, 'Range2',       1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  9, 'Range2',       0 FROM DUAL
  )
  SELECT r.Column_A,
         r.Column_B,
         a.rid
  FROM   ranges r
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT ROWID  AS rid,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Column_B ORDER BY ROWNUM ) AS rn,
           Column_B
    FROM   table_a
  ) a
  ON ( r.Column_B = a.Column_B AND MOD( a.rn, 2 ) = r.rn )
) src
ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET Column_A = src.Column_A
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT ( Column_A, Column_B )
  VALUES ( src.Column_A, src.Column_B );
```

And the output would be:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_a;
```

> ```
> COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B    
> -------: | :-----------
>        1 | Descriptions
>       10 | Descriptions
>       42 | Range1      
>        0 | Range2      
>        9 | Range2      
>        0 | Range2      
>       50 | Range1
> ```

You can see that an extra row for `Range1` has been created and all the rows for `Range2` have been updated.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fd4750c0f9a71ebd13577bc0533dbdf1)*